# How to run python script from another python script and passing parameter as Realtime?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want code like this:

```
process=run('2.PY')
whilt ScriptRunning(process):
   txt=input()
   output=pass(process,txt)
   print(output )
```

I have two scripts
Script 1.py
Script 2.py
I want to run script 2 with script 1. between them passing parameter.
My second script has the ability to stay in zombie mode and wait for input.
I tried with the subprocess module, but after execution, it does not wait to receive input and completes the process.
out put :

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'python3 TC-Bot/src/run.py'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
if not err:
    result = out.split('\n')
    for lin in result:
        if not lin.startswith('#'):
            print(lin)
else:
    print(err)
```

Comment: Don't you need to also pipe stdin so it can "wait for input"?

Comment: Does it have to be a subprocess? My guess is that you'd be better off using threads instead. You can use one thread for collecting user input, and save that to a shared memory location. It would be useful if you could explain exactly what you're trying to achieve in broader terms as well. It may be solvable without even using threads.

Comment: Your first code block has a while loop around your call to the subprocess, so it's waiting for that other process? I think you may just be looking to use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) inside a single process?